# how to test fileStream?

Tags: filestream

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.xls", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
ExcelWriter writer = new ExcelWriter(stream);
writer.BeginWrite();
writer.WriteCell (1, 0, "No");
    writer.WriteCell (1, 1, "Status");
    writer.WriteCell (1, 2, "Date");
    writer.WriteCell (1, 3, "Time");
    writer.WriteCell (1, 4, "Unit");
    writer.WriteCell (1, 5, "Total");
writer.EndWrite();
    stream.Close();
```

i wrote this code in button.when i first click it work.but when i click again it got error :mono system.io.ioexception sharing violation on path....how to fix it?please help.thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to save the file in a place where you're not allowed to. Try specifying another location for the file or fix access rights. What environment is this?

Comment: Does ExcelWriter have a Dispose() method?